# What is the difference between ps and ps -e command in linux

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

What is the difference between ps and ps -e command in linux ? ps -e gives a longer list .

Comment: Run `man ps` - people have already taken the time (years ago) to document this. Also, try a google search for the same terms: ["man ps"](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+ps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual,

> By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID
>   (euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal
>   as the invoker.

For example, if you open a gnome-terminal and give the ps command, it will list all your processes started from that terminal.

`ps -e` lists all the processes in the system.